# JTable needs resfresh to show change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My `JTable` need to a refresh when for example delete a row.

My code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if (e.getSource() == dellButton) {
      int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (selectedRow >= 0) {
            try {
                int rowID = (int) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
                int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                rstm.removeRecord(rowID ,rowIndex);
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Select a row");
        }
    }
}
 ....
```

My table model Class:

```
public class ResultSetTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultSet;
private ResultSetMetaData metaData;
private int numberOfRows;
private boolean connectedToDatabase = false;

public ResultSetTableModel(String driver, String url,
        String username, String password, String query)
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    statement = connection.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    connectedToDatabase = true;
    updateFromDatabase(query);
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }

    try {
        String className = metaData.getColumnClassName(column + 1);

        return Class.forName(className);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Object.class;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }
    try {
        return metaData.getColumnCount();

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }
    try {
        return metaData.getColumnName(column + 1);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
        throws IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }

    try {
        resultSet.absolute(row + 1);
        return resultSet.getObject(column + 1);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}

public void updateFromDatabase(String query)
        throws SQLException, IllegalStateException {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not Connected to Database");
    }
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

    resultSet.last();                   // move to last row
    numberOfRows = resultSet.getRow();  // get row number      

    fireTableStructureChanged();
}

public void disconnectFromDatabase() {
    if (!connectedToDatabase) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connectedToDatabase = false;
    }
}

public void removeRecord(int userID , int userRow) throws SQLException {
    String deleteQuery = "delete from mytable where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
    pStatement.setInt(1, userID);
    int rowsAffected = pStatement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Affected rows are: " + rowsAffected);

    fireTableRowsDeleted(userRow,userRow);
}
}
```

I use `fireTableRowsDeleted()` in table model , but not work!

Comment: You're calling fireTableRowsDeleted() to tell the view that a row has been deleted, but you don't delete any row from the table model: the row hasn't really been deleted from the model. Also, the call to notify() doesn't make any sense. And also, row indices in the view (JTable) are not necessarily the same as row indices in the model. Use JTable.convertRowIndexToModel().

Comment: @JBNizet What is your mean? I delete row by `deleteQuery` in my database

Comment: The JTable doesn't read its rows from the database. It reads its rows from its TableModel.

Comment: Once your add data to your TableModel, it's 'disconnected' from the database. Changes to the table will not automatically reflect to the database and vice versa.

Comment: @JBNizet Where should use `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel()` ?

Comment: table.getSelectedRow() returns a *view* row index. Before passing the row index to the model, it must be changed to a *model* row index using convertRowIndexToModel() (for example, fireTableRowsDeleted() must pass a model row index, and not a view row index). The row index is the same in the view and the model, except if you sort rows or filter them. The same goes for column indices, which are the same until you reorder columns by dragging and dropping them.

Comment: @JBNizet I update code and output...

Comment: Remove that call to notify(). It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JBNizet I remove `notify()` , So what is next step?

Comment: The next step is to actually remove the (right) row from the model before calling fireTableRowsDeleted().

Comment: @JBNizet Can you explain more?

Comment: Show us the code of your table model, so that I can explain with your code, rather than code I would have written.

Comment: @JBNizet I add full code of my table model...

Comment: You're using an always-connected JDBC resultset to implement the model of your table. What you need to realize is that, when you delete a row from the database, you don't decrement the number of rows stored in the table model, and you don't re-execute the query so that the result set contains the new state of the database. What I would do instead is to read everything from the database to a List and use this list to implement the model. When you delete a row, you delete it from the database AND from the list, or you delete it from the database and you re-read the list from the database.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want to change my table model structure, Is there any other solution?

Comment: Yes. Re-execute the query, reset the row count, and reopen a new resultset each time you delete a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood your problem, you think that the Deleting a Row from SQL has a connection with JTable, But actually it's not, after deleting the row from SQL you have to again set the Model of the Jtable or if you don't want to set the model again just change the TableModel by its method .removeRow() this will delete the row from that model and your table will automatically show the change.

```
public class d10 extends JFrame {

DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
Vector<Vector<Object>> doubleVector = new Vector<>();
Vector<Object> singleVector = new Vector<>();
Vector<Object> ColumnNames = new Vector<>();
Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
static String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
public JTable table;

public static Connection connectToDb() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
}

public d10() {
    try {
        con = connectToDb();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from mytable");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        doubleVector = new Vector<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            singleVector = new Vector<>();
            singleVector.add(rs.getInt(1));
            singleVector.add(rs.getString(2));
            doubleVector.add(singleVector);
        }
        ColumnNames = new Vector<>();
        ColumnNames.add("ID1");
        ColumnNames.add("Name1");

        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(doubleVector, ColumnNames);
        table = new JTable(tableModel);

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 500);
        setLocation(400, 120);
        setVisible(true);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you are using a very complex code, the work you are trying is very easy, just a few lines code without making any new class. If you want I can give you the code from which you can delete the rows from SQL as well as from the Table but using your code is very difficult.

Comment: mybeautifulfuture@gmail.com

Comment: Please check your inbox

Comment: @Sajjad getting/giving private help is **not** what this site is for - either solve it here or leave it ...

Comment: @kleopatra if you have any solution, We are waiting for it

Comment: @Sajjad sorry to say (and repeating myself): you wouldn't understand the answer anyway (too many basics missing), so I suggest you grab a decent tutorial and start over, taking one step after the other.